# Jacoco method missed count can't detect mockk tests

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jacoco, mockk

Jacoco keeps reporting my missed method counts being high while I've actually been having good coverage with mockk, any idea why Jacoco method counts can't pick up mockk coverages? And are there any other test coverage libraries that work well with mockk? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with mockk coverages? mockk is used to mock objects. If you mock an object of course the code is not tested.

Comment: I meant I was mocking with mockk instead of Mockito. The issue is when I run the unit tests, which uses JUnit 5 and Mockk, pretty sure some lines are covered by the test, but it's not picked up by the coverage

Comment: Please add some code to your question so that we can help you further. Thanks.